# Multiple listeners reading from the same stream in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I need two different listeners to read the input coming from a readable stream.
They seem to have a race condition, and I want to make sure I get this right...

When I use .on('data') - each listener gets back the same chunk and can read it.

When I use .on('readable') - the first listener to catch the event will read from the buffer, and the second listener will get an empty buffer?

Meaning I cannot use .on('readable') event when I have TWO listeners?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. When the **readable** event is emitted, both the listeners listen. However, the first to call the **read()** function would get the data and second one would get an empty buffer because it's the same input stream being read twice and only a single chunk was present.
2. When the **data** event is emitted the listener receives the chunk of data being read from the stream. So all the listeners receive the same data.

**[EDIT]** In detail how it works:

All readable streams begin in 2 modes: **flowing** and **paused**. All Readable streams begin in paused mode by default but they can be switched to the flowing mode using any of the three methods:
1. Attaching a 'data' event handler to the stream
2. Calling the stream.resume() method
3. Calling the stream.pipe() method to send the data to a Writable.

When you use any of the above method the stream starts to flow. It doesn't care if the **data** listeners are attached to the stream and there's a possibility of losing the data. Internally, the **read()** method is called on the stream and whatever data that is being accumulated in the internal buffer is read and emitted to the listeners. The memory usage is quite low.

When you attach a **readable** listener on your stream, it takes priority over the **data** listener and hence your stream remains in the **paused** mode. In the paused mode, you've to explicitly read the data from the internal buffer by calling the **read()** method. When the readable data is available it keeps on getting accumulated in the internal buffer until the read() method is called explicitly or the stream is resumed. You can specify the size in bytes of the chunk to be read from the internal buffer or all the available data is returned. When read() is called **data** event is also emitted with the chunk of data read. After consuming this data, the internal buffer is emptied. So when you have multiple **readable** events attached and try to consume from the same internal buffer, you are not able to get the same data multiple times.

My suggestion to you would be have just one **readable** listener and multiple **data** listeners. Having a **readable** would give you the flexibility to read when you want without missing any data. And with the **data** event handlers, you would be able to get that data in all the handlers.

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR**: The data event will get the data to as many listeners as you like, but only if the listener will get attached before the data is read, so use `pipe` method to copy the data to two `PassThrough` streams and read from each of those separately.

**Here's how in detail:**

First what we need to understand: A single stream can only produce the `data` event only once per a chunk of data. This is because the stream object does not "know" who's reading - a response is read and that's it.

Now, just reading your question I would answer - how come? The event will be run twice, because every data event listener will be called... unless you actually set the listener in the `readable` event...

Let's assume that you set up something like this:

```
response.on("data", function A(chunk) {...});
response.on("readable", function B() {
    response.on("data", function C(chunk) {...});
});
```

Now when a chunk `1` comes `A()` will receive chunk: `1`. If the stream `drain`s afterwards (meaning the response is so slow it cannot feed any new data) it will pause. Only after that the stream may become `readable` again and then `B()` function will setup a listener for `C()`... **but**... function `A()` is already reading the `chunk` as we do that so `C()` will work on the next stream only.

Now as Swati Anand mentioned, you could use the same event listener - but, in my opinion, would be killing the whole beauty of streams. Using a `pipe` instead will be much more elegant, like this:

```
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
const data1 = new PassThrough();
const data2 = new PassThrough();

response.pipe(data1).on("data", function A(){...});
response.pipe(data2);

// when you're ready
data2.on("data", function C(){...});
```

The idea behind this is - instead of listening on any events on the original stream, we create two pass-through ones that are like "clones" and read the `data` there. This way no data get's lost for each parts of the program.

The [node.js stream docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_three_states) are actually the best read about the data flow. Try to read it as a plumbing story - with connected pipes etc.

Comment: So the data2 PassThrough is serving as a buffer.  Unlimited size?  If not unlimited size then after that limit is reached it must either block the first channel or drop data on the second. If unlimited size eventually the system would run out of memory.  Why is the data1 PassThrough necessary?  What advantage does is offer?

Comment: @CraigHicks no, data2 is serving as an additional backpressure - the response is not read as fast as the fastest consumer, but rather as the slower consumer. The system would not run out of memory, because the response would be read only after the `// when you're ready` part is called - otherwise the response is still paused.

Comment: I see what you mean - data1 reader is in no rush.  I agree this is much simpler than the selected answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use RxJS to make it easier as the following

```
const { Observable, fromStream } = require('rxjs');
const { share } = require('rxjs/operators');
// By declaring this observable, the same stream will be use for every subscribers
const stream$ = Observable.fromStream(yourStream).share();

const subscriber1 = stream$.subscribe(console.log);
const subscriber2 = stream$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: i cannot find fromStream method from rxjs, what's the current equivalence?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr use a PassThrough stream

```
const stream = require('stream');

const pt = new stream.PassThrough();

response.pipe(pt);

pt.on("data", data => {
  // observe the data
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, none of the answers worked for me very well. This did though:

```js
  let b = 0
  const passReceiver = new PassThrough()
  const passWatcher = new PassThrough()
  passWatcher.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log('data: ', b++) // or any other "watching" you may desire
    passReceiver.write(chunk)
  })
  passWatcher.on('end', () => {
    console.log('passWatcher end')
    passReceiver.end()
  })
  // that's the setup, then you pipe into passWatcher and out of passReceiver

  SomeReadableStream.pipe(passWatcher)
  passReceiver.pipe(someWritableStream)
```